# Are both definitions to 3NF equal?

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf

From [3rd Normal Form Definition](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/third-normal-form-3nf.php):

> A database is in third normal form if it satisfies the following
>   conditions:
>
> - It is in second normal form.
> - There is no transitive functional dependency.
>
> By transitive functional dependency, we mean we have the following
>   relationships in the table: A is functionally dependent on B, and B is
>   functionally dependent on C. In this case, C is transitively dependent
>   on A via B.

My lucturer gave us a second defenition for 3NF:

> Non-prime attributes cannot depend on any set that isn't a super-key
>   (transitive dependency).

Are both definitions to 3NF equal? Why?

Comment: What is tacking on "(transitive dependency)" trying to say?

Comment: I think it has the same meaning like this article explains: https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-11-database-third-normal-form-explained-in-simple-english/ but I'm not sure..

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It is an irrelevant term stuck on the end. But something else might mean something. PS The definitions in this post & your links are all wrong. Read a published textbook.

Comment: I suspected that something is wrong here, any chance for referencing me to any better definition on that subject?

Comment: I have a draft answer but I must research/prove more because in composing I have come to suspect certain definitions that I had thought ok. Many textbooks are free online (like, 2 dozen); but many are sloppy, and few cover a range of definitions. From Zaniolo's paper introducing the correct form of the 2nd above: "A relation R is 3NF iff for every nontrivial FD of R, X -> A,  
(a) X is a superkey for R, or  
(b) A is a [candidate] key attribute for R." But its "transitively dependent" definition, attributed to Codd via Berstein, doesn't need 2NF. I'm looking for the 2NF+ definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume there exists an attribute `X` that depends on a set of attributes that is not a Super-Key. This would imply that the set that `X` depends on contains at least one attribute `np1` that is NOT part of a Super-Key. But `np1` will in turn depend on a Super-Key. 
Because `np1` depends on the Super-Key, one (and only one) of the following will be true :

**A.**  `X` only depends on the Super-Key => **this contradicts our initial assumption**

or

**B.**  `X` only depends on `np1` => **this introduces a transitive dependency**

If X would truly depend on both the SK and np1, then [SK, np1] would become a superkey - which is not possible.

So the only possible conclusion is that the two definitions are equal.

Comment: You said "`np1` will in turn depend on a Super-Key". How you conclude that? it may depend on `np2` , while `np2` is not part of the Super-Key and `np2` depends on `np3` and so on until `np-N` which is a Super-Key.

Comment: @StavAlfi - yes, np1 may not directly depend on an SK, but you eventually arrive at a SuperKey, as you have described. So np1 will depend on the SK either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Both are Similar statements but the second one is ameliorated and therefore much more fascinating.

> Specifically: a relation is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and **no non-prime attribute is dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the relation.** A non-prime attribute of a relation is an attribute that is not a part of any candidate key of the relation.

A candidate key is a Super Key from which no more Attribute can be pruned.

The highlighted part gives the conclusion that **The database is in 2NF form**(that was your first excerpt)